# Is there a way of redirecting user to same session in google assistant action after he is directed to a webpage

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have Build an action to google assitant using dialogflow.I was stuck in a situation where user will be provided with weblink in between conversation.Once he clicks on link he will be directed to webpage to upload image.After he uploads an image i want to redirect him to the same session in google action.Is there a way which i can redirect user back to same session of action.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to send them back to the same session?

Comment: My conversation flow isn't complete and I was not using any sign-in authentication for the user.I am depending on session Id to identify the user.To continue the conversation i want to go back to the same session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to return to the same session, and this isn't possible.

You can [store data across sessions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/save-data#saving_data_across_conversations) in the `conv.user.storage` object as long as the user is verified (the system can identify them or their voice) and has not disabled data storage. If you're using node.js, it might look something like this:

```
app.intent('Save Sum', (conv) => {
  if (conv.user.verification === 'VERIFIED') {
    conv.user.storage.sum = conv.data.sum;
    conv.close(`Alright, I'll store that for next time. See you then.`);
  } else {
    conv.close(`I can't save that right now, but we can add ` +
      `new numbers next time!`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation.I was thinking that verified user is the one who has already signed in with our action and we can't access user storage for un-verified user.So I was searching for other ways of storing data.But i realised through documents that it is not the case after going through your explanation.

Comment: I've clarified a little about what "verified" means. Glad this helps you out!

Answer (score 1):

Its better you use account linking **https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity** of google actions to retrieve user information throughout entire conversation even if he is opening link and then coming back as returning user can make the person to continue with your conversation flow.

Thanks